# Google Maps display markers as created not all at once as an array

Tags: arrays, google-maps-markers, marker

How do I get the markers to display as they are being created?  Currently, they are added to the array and displayed all at once.

Your assistance is appreciated…along with any coding improvement suggestions.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
<head>
<title>Maps</title>
<style type="text/css"> 
html, body { height: 100%; } 
</style>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        var side_bar_html = ""; 
        var map = null;
        var markers = [];
        var sites = [['Action Family Counseling Alcohol & Drug Treatment', 34.2807649, -118.7094014, 1, 'Action Family Counseling Alcohol & Drug Treatment<br>4380 Apricot Road<br>Simi Valley, CA  93063', 'Company'],['AIM - Access for Infants and Mothers', 34.217982, -119.147809, 21, 'AIM - Access for Infants and Mothers<br>2220 East Gonzales Road<br>Oxnard, CA  93036', 'Company'],['Ananda Marga Universal Relief Team', 39.086355, -77.1889489, 111, 'Ananda Marga Universal Relief Team<br>2502 Lindley TER <br>Rockville, MD  20805', 'Company'],['Area Agency on Aging', 34.2698398, -119.2148903, 9, 'Area Agency on Aging<br>646 County Square Dr.<br>Ventura, CA  93003', 'Company'],['Area Christians Taking Initiative On Needs (ACTION', 34.2087312, -119.0315009, 2, 'Area Christians Taking Initiative On Needs (ACTION<br>406 Constitution Avenue<br>Camarillo, CA  93012', 'Company'],['Berylwood Family Resource Center', 34.2684132, -118.7516168, 3, 'Berylwood Family Resource Center<br>2300 Heywood Street<br>Simi Valley, CA  93065', 'Company'],['Big Brothers/Big Sisters of Ventura County', 34.220567, -119.062037, 5, 'Big Brothers/Big Sisters of Ventura County<br>445 Rosewood Avenue<br>Camarillo, CA  93010', 'Company'],['Boys and Girls Club of Camarillo ', 34.2293953, -119.0307973, 8, 'Boys and Girls Club of Camarillo <br>1500 Temple Ave. <br>Camarillo, CA  93010', 'Company'],['Boys and Girls Club of Moorpark', 34.288225, -118.884874, 6, 'Boys and Girls Club of Moorpark<br>200 Casey Road<br>Moorpark, CA  93021', 'Company']];
        var x = 121;
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ 
            size: new google.maps.Size(150, 50)
        });
        var pinImage = [];
        var i = 0;
        var html = '';
        // company is green
        // lodging is red
        pinImage["Company"] = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=C|00AF33", new google.maps.Size(21, 34), new google.maps.Point(0,0), new google.maps.Point(10, 34));;
        pinImage["Lodging"] = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=L|FE7569", new google.maps.Size(21, 34), new google.maps.Point(0,0), new google.maps.Point(10, 34));;
        var pinShadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_shadow",
            new google.maps.Size(40, 37),
            new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            new google.maps.Point(12, 35)
        );

        function initialize() {
            var centerMap = new google.maps.LatLng(39.828175, -98.5795);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 4,
                center: centerMap,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.close();
            });
            displayMarkers();
            show("Company");
            hide("Lodging");
            makeSidebar();
        }

        function displayMarkers() {
            var siteLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(sites[i][1], sites[i][2]);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: siteLatLng,
                map: map,
                title: sites[i][0],
                zIndex: sites[i][3],
                html: sites[i][4],
                icon: pinImage[sites[i][5]],
                shadow: pinShadow
            });
            marker.mycategory = sites[i][5];
            marker.myname = sites[i][0];
            markers.setVisible = true;
            markers.push(marker);
            markers[i].setVisible(true);
            var contentString = "Some content";
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
                infowindow.setContent(this.html);
                infowindow.open(map, this);
            });
            html += '<a href="javascript:myclick(' + i + ')">' + markers[i].myname + '<\/a><br>';
            document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = html;
            i++
            if (i < sites.length) {
                document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = 'Loading record ' + i + ' of ' + sites.length;
                setTimeout("displayMarkers()", 10);
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = 'Check/Uncheck boxes for Markers to display.';
            }
        }

        function show(category) {
            for (var i=0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                if (markers[i].mycategory == category) {
                    markers[i].setVisible(true);
                }
            }
            document.getElementById(category+"box").checked = true;
        }

        function hide(category) {
            for (var i=0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                if (markers[i].mycategory == category) {
                    markers[i].setVisible(false);
                }
            }
            document.getElementById(category+"box").checked = false;
            infowindow.close();
        }

        function boxclick(box,category) {
            if (box.checked) {
                show(category);
            }
            else {
                hide(category);
            }
            makeSidebar();
        }

        function myclick(i) {
            google.maps.event.trigger(markers[i],"click");
        }

        function makeSidebar() {
            var html = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                if (markers[i].getVisible()) {
                    html += '<a href="javascript:myclick(' + i + ')">' + markers[i].myname + '<\/a><br>';
                }
            }
            document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = html;
        }
    </script>

    <form action="#">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                <p align="center">
                <img src="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=C|00AF33">
                <br />
                <strong>Company:</strong>
                <input type="checkbox" id="Companybox" onclick="boxclick(this,'Company')" /><br>121 Records</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                <p align="center">
                <img src="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=L|FE7569">
                <br />
                <strong>Lodging:</strong>
                <input type="checkbox" id="Lodgingbox" onclick="boxclick(this,'Lodging')" /><br>121 Records</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <div id="counter"></div>
    <table border="1" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" bgcolor="#990000" height="500">
        <tr>
            <td bordercolor="#000000" bgcolor="#000000" valign="top">
            <div class="notscrollable" id="map_canvas" style="width: 625px; height: 500px">
            </div>
            </td>
            <td valign="top" bgcolor="#EBEBEB" bordercolor="#000000">
            <div style="font-size:13px">
                <div class="scrollable" id="side_bar" style="height: 500px; overflow: scroll">
                </div>
            </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>



<body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.

Removed var map from beginning and moved a few things around.